# Has this type of Discrete Product Distribution been studied before??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I was messing around with some random number $S=(1,2,...,n|n\in \mathbb{Z^+})$

Then I wonder, what would the discrete distribution of the random variable $X(k_1,k_2)=k_1*k_2,\  k_1,k_2\in S$ looks like. (Both $k_1$ and $k_2$ are uniform so choosing any integer would have a $\frac1n$ probability) I don't know much about probability so I couldn't figure it out.

I also know that it is a discrete distribution. But if I divide the intervals from $1$ to $n^2$ into $n$ equal intervals with equal length, i.e. $A_i=(k|(i-1)n+1 \le k \le in)$

After searching online I observe that only continuous product distributions are studied but not for discrete cases. In which intervals will $P(X \in A_i)$ be the greatest?

Extra question: what will the ratio distribution $Y=\frac{k_1}{k_2}$ look like?

Comment: What are the distributions of $k_1$ and $k_2$? Uniform over $\{1,\dots,n\}$?

Comment: Im not sure if there is a general solution to this. I have tried working out a counting function to find out $P(X \in A_i)$ but couldn't simplify it.

Comment: @Augustin Yes sorry I didn't mention it. I will edit it